# Is it possible to assign promise data value to outside variable with react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it possible in react to assign promise data value to outside variable?

I want to do something like:

```
export default class LocationSearchInput extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {address: ''}
}

handleChange = (address) => {
    this.setState({ address });
};

handleSelect = (address) => {
    geocodeByAddress(address)
        .then(results => getLatLng(results[0]))
        .then(latLng => console.log(latLng))
        .catch(error => console.error('Error', error));
};
render() { ........
```

In this example, I get what I want: latLng, but i can't use it outside. Its inside SearchBox.js file I want to include it inside another Map.js file. I’m new to this, many thanks!

Comment: you need a parent - child - siblings relationship between `Map.js` and `LocationSearchInput`

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this scenario would be have a function in the topMost parent which will need to use `latLng` and let that make the API call and save the `LatLng` in state and pass this value down as props to `LocationSearchInput` and other components that need it

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  handleGeocodeByAddress(address) {
     geocodeByAddress(address)
        .then(results => getLatLng(results[0]))
        .then(latLng => this.setState({ latLng }))
        .catch(error => console.error('Error', error));
  }
  render() {
     return <Child layLng={this.state.latLng} handleGeocodeByAddress={handleGeocodeByAddress} />
  }
}
```

and call the parent function from child

```
export default class LocationSearchInput extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {address: ''}
    }

    handleChange = (address) => {
        this.setState({ address });
    };

    handleSelect = (address) => {
        this.props.handleGeocodeByAddress(address);
    };
    render() { ........
```

Comment: I'm getting always infintiy loop when putting  <Map layLng={this.state.latLng} /> inside return

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way to do this would be store your `latLng` on the global `window` object like this:

```
window.latLng = latLng;
```

You can then use it from `Map.js` by accessing it as `window.latLng`.

However, this is not a very good practice. It pollutes your global object (although using a namespace mitigates this to some extent) and since you are retrieving `latLng` asynchronously, the variable may be unavailable when `Map.js` code tries accessing it.

A better way of handling this would be to pass the `latLng` value up to a parent component and hand it back down to wherever `Map.js` needs it. You can also emit an event and capture it from `Map.js`

Comment: I want to do this using props and state but can't (